# Shell is option given

Tags: shell, options

I have a couple of arguments inside a list (array, e.g. `$@`) and I'd like to know if the option `-v` is in the list.

In Python I would simply do:

```
verbose = "-v" in sys.argv
```

How do I achieve that in shell without much code?

Comment: Imho, the best way to do argument parsing in shell scripts is with `getopt`. See `man getopt`.

Comment: @HalosGhost `getopts` is easier to use and more portable than `getopt`. It's less powerful, but the power of `getopt` is rarely useful in a shell script.

Comment: @Gilles, I recommend `getopt` only because I'm so familiar with its C counterpart, but I will have to look into `getopts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a shell script, you call the [`getopts`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-getopts) function in a loop. There is a code example in the [dash manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dash.1.html).

---

Note that your Python code is not correct except in extremely simple cases. It detects an argument `-v` anywhere on the line, even if it's the argument of another option or after non-option arguments. The correct way to parse options in Python is with `argparse` or `optparse`.

Comment: I know I normally use optparse (or argparse if available) but I often only need very simple script with just a few options.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
for i in "$@"
do
  [ "$i" = -v ] && verbose=1
done
```

Comment: This is analogous to the given Python snippet, but it's not what you should do: it triggers even if `-v` appears as the argument of another option, or after `--`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what the user wants. Not all programs have options with value as separate argument and/or choose the usual meaning of `--`.